# Result of `na.omit()` not behaving the same as pre-cleaned dataset when using `lapply()`

Tags: r

I am trying to run `wilcox.test()` on several subsets of data using the `lapply()` function. The data is grouped in the first column of my data frame by a text identifier (site name), and there are two other columns for data from 2013 and 2017 on which I'm running the wilcox test. About 10% of my 500 rows of data have a missing value in either the 2013 or 2017 (or both) columns.

When I try to run the `lapply()` function shown below, I get the error:

```
df<-read.csv("myfile.csv",header=T)

split.df<-split(df,df$Site)
lapply(split.df, function(g) wilcox.test(g$2013, g$2017, paired=T)
```

> Error in wilcox.test.default(g$2013, g$2017, Paired = T) :    not
>   enough (finite) 'x' observations `

I have tried cleaning the data frame of n/a's using the `na.omit()` and `na.exclude()` functions:

```
df<-na.omit(df)
```

OR

```
df<-na.exclude(df)
```

When running the same `split`, followed by `lapply` as written above after either omitting or excluding the NA's, I get the same error.

If I clean the data up in Excel before importing by removing all rows with missing values in either the 2013 or 2017 row, and then import the data, the `lapply()` function runs correctly.

I am using RStudio, and I have looked at the dataframe at each step. After importing the raw data I have 500 observations. After using either the `na.omit()` or `na.exclude()` the dataframe still shows 500 rows, but the rows which had NA values are 'masked' in that the row number is skipped. For example, if rows 5, 8 and 10 had NA's in them, the cleaned dataframe would show rows 1,2,3,4,6,9,11....and so on. If I directly compare row 12 of the cleaned dataset and raw dataset they will be the same values (hence why I think the `na.omit()` and `na.exclude()` are simply hiding or masking the rows with NA's).

When I import the dataframe after cleaning it up in excel first, I see that there are truly only 450 rows. I think the error from the `lapply()` function may be because the `na.omit()` and `na.exclude()` aren't actually removing those rows from the dataframe.

Is there a function to truly delete the rows with NA's, or am I totally on the wrong path here? Any tips are appreciated.

Edit:

Example data here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av1rL-HNLDNsgZ84P86y953iCXxnjA

Example code, which gives the aforementioned error:

```
names(df)
df.split<-split(df, df$Site)
df.split
lapply(df.split, function(g) wilcox.test(g$y2013, g$y2017, paired=T))
```

If the linked csv file is cleaned up manually by removing rows with missing values, the above code works correctly, with the following output:

$D03

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 220, p-value = 0.01681
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$D04

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 158, p-value = 0.0008411
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$D08

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 96, p-value = 1.146e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$D09

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 44, p-value = 0.0002089
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$D11

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 153, p-value = 0.0006289
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$Platform1

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 285, p-value = 0.05974
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$Platform2

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 43, p-value = 0.002726
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

$Platform3

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test
```

data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
V = 127, p-value = 0.002817
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you can add an example using which we can reproduce the same issue you are facing.

Comment: For sure! I tried making a smaller subset of my data, but I can't get the same error to pop up. Is there a good way for me to post my larger dataset for you guys to have to run? I can post my code in the meantime.

Comment: So if you remove the `NA` rows it works. What is your expected output then?

Comment: Added expected output to original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `complete.cases` to remove `NA` values and then apply the test

```
df1 <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
df.split <- split(df1, df1$Site)

lapply(df.split, function(g) wilcox.test(g$y2013, g$y2017, paired=TRUE))

#$D03

#   Wilcoxon signed rank test

#data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
#V = 220, p-value = 0.01681
#alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0


#$D04

#   Wilcoxon signed rank test

#data:  g$y2013 and g$y2017
#V = 158, p-value = 0.0008411
#alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

#...
#...
```

Comment: Beautiful! I had tried complete.cases when testing ways to get rid of na values, but I kept getting errors. I must have had something slightly wrong with the code for that function since yours worked.